# Why is the type "Set[str]" seen as incompatible by PyCharm when "set" is allowed?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm, type-hinting

I have a simple function that converts a set of strings into a dictionary:

```py
def decoder(text)
    return dict(enumerate(text))
```

I want to ensure with type hinting that developers pass a `set` of strings:

```py
def decoder(text: Set[str]) -> Dict[int, str]:
    return dict(enumerate(text))
```

This raises the following warning in PyCharm:

> Unexpected type(s): (enumerate[str]) Possible types: (Mapping) (Iterable[Tuple[Any, Any]])

It seems that the `dict(...)` is being past the type `enumerate[str]` and PyCharm is complaining, because that's not a valid type for a dictionary. Which is confusing me because enumerating a set should yield a tuple which is the correct type.

The warning goes away if I just type hint that the `text` is a `set`:

```py
def decoder(text: set) -> Dict[int, str]:
    return dict(enumerate(text))
```

The above works but nothing is warning the developers not to pass a `Set[int]` or other unexpected types.

What could I be doing wrong here?

Comment: There is an open issue for this bug: [False positive: dict(enumerate(list)) unexpected type](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-35037)

Comment: @Georgy thanks, I'll leave this question here for Google and hopefully they'll fix it soon.